# Regex to categorize phone numbers that 2 of the last 4 digits the same.

Tags: regex

Regex to categorize phone numbers. Numbers with 2 of the same digit in the last 4  not adjacent to each other are easier to remember and therefore more valuable. So given 10 digit number how can I match if 2 of the last 4 digits are the same non consecutively? Ex. 2155553747, 2158558284, 7034651215. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That won't be easy with regex, it's much easier to do this in regular programming code. What language are you programming in?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please share to see where you are stuck. What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular expression for that, and you are okay with the condition, that *at least* 2 digits of the last 4 digits are the same, you could use the following regular expression:

```
^\d{6}(?:(\d)\d\d\1|(\d)\d\2\d|(\d)\3\d\d|\d(\d)\d\4|\d(\d)\5\d|\d\d(\d)\6)$
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/t6n1uP/1

Answer (score 0):

Masochistic approach:

```
/^\d{6}(\d?0[^0]{1,2}0|\d?1[^1]{1,2}1|\d?2[^2]{1,2}2|\d?3[^3]{1,2}3|\d?4[^4]{1,2}4|\d?5[^5]{1,2}5|\d?6[^6]{1,2}6|\d?7[^7]{1,2}7|\d?8[^8]{1,2}8|\d?9[^9]{1,2}9)/m
```

[A test](https://regex101.com/r/nYrdoy/1)

Far from ideal, but something to start from